# javascript value to html and php

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I am trying to get and id of an div element with this line of code;

```
console.log(this.nextSibling.previousSibling);
```

I am able to display the id of and element in the console but my question is how can i pass this id to the HTML and php for further coding. I tried following lines of code

```
var xlow = ($(this).nextSibling.previousSibling);
$('#testx').getElementById('hello ' + xlow);
```

and try to print the testx using print_r but the site gives me an error with undefined variable testx.

I am not good at javascript and jquery so any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
    <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
<script language"javascript" type"text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function(){
  $(".view_parent_furnace_boiler").droppable();
});

  var xPos = 0;
  var yPos = 0;
    $(document).ready(function() {

   `enter code here` $(".device-container").draggable(
      {
      grid: [10, 10],
        containment: "#picture_container",
        drag: function(){
            var offset = $(this).offset();
            var xPos = offset.left;
            var yPos = offset.top;

            $('#posX').text('x: ' + xPos);
            $('#posY').text('y: ' + yPos);
        },
        stop: function(){
            var finalOffset = $(this).offset();

            var finalxPosX = finalOffset.left - 130;
            var finalyPosY = finalOffset.top - 203;

            $('#finalX').text('Final X: ' + finalxPosX);
            $('#finalY').text('Final Y: ' + finalyPosY);

            console.log( (100 / $('#picture_container').width())*finalxPosX );
            console.log( (100 / $('#picture_container').height())*finalyPosY );


            //this prints out the value in console
            console.log(this.nextSibling.previousSibling);


            var x = ( (100 / $('#picture_container').width())*finalxPosX );
            var y = ( (100 / $('#picture_container').height())*finalyPosY );
        },

        revert: 'invalid'
    });

  /* window.alert(this.nextSibling.previousSibling = xlow);*/

// $(".device-container").draggable();
});
```

Comment: i am trying to pass the id to HTML form to update the table. but for now if i would be able to print the id in Html i think i would be able to figure out the rest.

Comment: There's a whole lot of information missing from your question, including how you're trying to link Javascript, HTML, and JQuery together.

Comment: I just updated my post and added the code here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm wondering why you are using `nextSibling` and then `previousSibling`.

```
var myId = $(this)attr('id');
```

Should do work for you. And If you need it inside any html just use `val()` for forms inputs or `text()` for other elements. Like:

```
$( "#myDiv" ).text(myId);
```

Comment: I have a div within a div so i had to figure out how to print out my elements inside the div.

Comment: You were right about the nextSibling and previousSibling. the attr('id') and .text() method worked for me. Thank you for the help!!!